# Trouble with Twitter Login Button

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, twitter

In my iOS App (Objective-C) I authenticate a user with a TWTRLogInButton.

As per the instructions, I started off with putting this in the **viewDidLoad** of my **viewcontroller.m**

```
TWTRLogInButton *logInButton = [TWTRLogInButton buttonWithLogInCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
///
}];
    logInButton.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:logInButton];
```

With all the other configurations in place, that works just fine.

However, in order to have more control over the position and size of the Twitter Login Button, I would like to add that button by means of interface builder.

So, in my **viewcontroller.h** I added:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet TWTRLogInButton *twitterButton;
```

On my .xib (yes, I know) I added a UIView, classed it as a "TWTRLogInButton" and connected it to 'twitterButton'

Then, in my **viewcontroller.m**, in viewDidLoad, I do

```
 self.twitterButton = [TWTRLogInButton buttonWithLogInCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
    ///
    }];
```

But somehow, when I tap the button, after the Twitter Dialog is dismissed, the completion is not called.

What gives?

Comment: `self.twitterButton = [TWTRLogInButton buttonWithLogInCompletion:...]`: That's overriding the `self.twitterButton` with no frame. Since it's an IBOutlet, if you check the address before and after that line it should be different. Check https://twittercommunity.com/t/ios-twtrloginbutton-was-created-with-no-completionblock-set/45724/2 It's the same explaination and gives the solutions.

Comment: Thanks! Why don't you post this as an answer, then I can reward you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's explained in the [Twitter Community forum](https://twittercommunity.com/t/ios-twtrloginbutton-was-created-with-no-completionblock-set/45724/2) and makes sense (didn't test it), but I'll post it here to have an answer on StackOverflow.

Your button is declared as such and is present and connected in your Storyboard/Xib:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet TWTRLogInButton *twitterButton;
```

From the [doc](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/appledocs/Classes/TWTRLogInButton.html) of `+(instancetype)buttonWithLogInCompletion:(TWTRLogInCompletion)completion` (there is `+(instancetype)`) and the doc says (I put in bold the important part)

> Returns **a new log in button** which launches Twitter log in when tapped
>   and calls completion when logging in succeeds or fails.

So when you do:

```
self.twitterButton = [TWTRLogInButton buttonWithLogInCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) { 
    //Code for completionHandler
}];
```

You are creating a whole new object and overriding the previous one connected to your xib/storyboard you "lose the connection" between your code and the one you previously set in your xib/storyboard.

How to fix it, the button has a property to set, the completion handler.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) TWTRLogInCompletion logInCompletion
```

So set it:

```
[self.twitterButton setLogInCompletion = ^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error){
    //Code for completionHandler
}];
```

Comment: I added my answer as Community Wiki, since I didn't really tested and question and answer were already existing on Twitter Community Forum. Feel free if possible to upvote/like (or other similar system they use) also the answer on the Twitter Community Forum.